# Apache Cassandra using cqlsh to LIST table_name

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I'm just starting out with Cassandra 3.7 and using the cqlsh terminal to create table input and view data. In previous versions of Cassandra the distribution came with cassandra-cli that allow you to view how the data is stored internally. The cassandra-cli does not appear to be in the 3.7 dist. The version of cqlsh is 5.0.1. It's supposed to be able to run the cli commands, but when I run 
'LIST tablename' i get no viable alternative at input...
Running the above command in cassandra-cli would give you an idea of how the data is stored internally. How can i run the same command in the cqlsh terminal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thrift was deprecated a bit ago and disabled by default so they eventually removed `cassandra-cli` (thrift client) from tree.

Worth noting that after 3.0 the output of `LIST` would no longer be a representation of whats internally stored anymore since the storage engine changed considerably.

Try using the [sstabledump](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/debugging-sstables-in-3-0-with-sstabledump) tool or [sstable-tools](https://github.com/tolbertam/sstable-tools) (dump command in cqlsh mode) to see the internal structure or look at sstables. Otherwise `SELECT * FROM tablename` would be equivalent of the `LIST` operation

Comment: sstabledump which is in the tools/bin dir needs a options to run. I've tried 'sstabledump -d filename.db' and the other options. Still can't seem to get it in Json format? I've also tried in the cqlsh terminal typing 'sstable-tools dump;' but that gives and error.

Comment: Sorry ignore last comment. Was a typo in my command. Thanks Chris! This works now!